# Integral representation of some operator monotone functions

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, monotone-functions

In many literature it is known that an operator monotone function can be represented in a form $$f(x)=a+bx+\int_{0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{t}{1+t^{2}}-\frac{1}{t+x} \right)d\mu(t).$$ I also know that the typical examples of operator monotone function is $-\frac{1}{x}$ and $\log x.$ For the first example I guess that $a=b=0,$ but I do not know how to find $\mu.$

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you so much.

Comment: Your question is how to represent $-\frac1x$ in that form?

Comment: Yes, I want to represent $-\frac{1}{x}$ using such integral representation..

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nevanlinna_function

Comment: Try $\mu = \delta_0$ ;-)

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp Thx so much :)